# Shared EventBus for multiple Applications and Containers for Reactor

Tags: spring, event-bus, project-reactor

I am looking how is it possible with Spring Boot and Reactor to have multiple applications (each one running on its own Spring Boot container) that use one common/shared EventBus running in a stand-alone container.
It is a Microservice environment with multiple applications, each of one specialized, and which should be called in a chain of events.

Is it possible?
This is the diagram representing the scenario:
[image]
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have one spring boot container with multiple applications and one shared eventBus? Or multiple spring boot containers, each running one application, and all these apps should share on bus running in its own container?

Comment: Hi. The scenario is the second one.
Many Spring boot containers, each running an application, and all these should share one Event Bus in its own container.
I post a diagram.

Comment: Did you have a look at reactor-net? http://projectreactor.io/docs/reference/#reactor-net

Comment: All examples are in Java 8, not groovy.

Comment: I think it would help people if you would translate the Hungarian texts on the otherwise very nice diagram. :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm understanding from question you want to enable moduling architecture i.e. couple of separate application would run on same or completely different server or may be in cloud.And this applications would or wouldn't interact with each other
If that's your criteria, then I would suggest you to go for the Microservice Architecture.
Using Spring Boot, Reactor and Netflix it's very popular topic nowadays. Below link might be helpfull for you to understand this stuff:
https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring